# Mobile-friendly Stripe receipt URL

Tags: stripe-payments

I hope I'm missing something obvious, but the receipt_url that is returned with the charge object does not display nicely on mobile browsers. Are there any request parameters that can be added to the URL to make it display correctly on mobile? There is no viewport meta tag on the page, so on mobile devices (Pixel 5 in this case), it looks like...

[image: Receipt URL demo on Google Pixel 5]

Comment: Unfortunately there aren't URL parameters that you can provide to change this as far as I am aware. You can try reaching out to Stripe's support team or your browser's support team to address how this is rendered. Add more details on your browser if you can, testing on my own Pixel 5 did not get the same results in either Firefox or Chrome. So this may also have something to do with your setup

Comment: I contacted support. They verified the issue and are working on a fix! Thanks Stripe team.